Allow retracting a suggested edit
Recently I made a suggested edit, but after clicking "save" I thought better of it. I discovered that there's no "retract edit" or "rollback" feature for suggested edits. Re-edit and "cancel" just cancels the re-edit. I could only ask reviewers to "cancel" the edit in the summary, which they did by rejecting it.
The issue of the inability to retract/cancel one's own suggested edit has been raised previously. For example:
How can I cancel an edit I made on another user's question or answer?
Cancel edit before it gets approved
Revoking own suggested edits
The answers to those fall into two categories, neither of which I think address the question.

Just edit the edit to change something else.

It can't be done. Don't worry. It'll just be rejected.


So change a possibly substantive, but undesired, edit into a frivolous one or wait until two (or possibly more) reviewers waste their time rejecting something that could have been avoided.
But wait, there's more (not mentioned elsewhere that I found). When I look at my editor stats, it says:


Nanigashi had 4 edit suggestions approved, 2 edit suggestions rejected, and 0 edit suggestions canceled.


I can find no other reference to "canceled" suggestions, which seems like exactly the point of this question. Is there supposed to be a way to cancel an edit (that's already been saved, of course)? Is it a feature that's only been implemented half way? (The stat is tracking something.) It seems to me that it would be worthwhile to implement the other half, if so.
EDIT: Thanks, @HenryEcker, for pointing to what canceled edits are. I think that whoever can edit Help pages should consider adding that explanation about proposedsuggested edits to /help/editing. The rest of my question/request about retraction remains.

Edit conflicts should categorize as "cancelled" instead of "rejected"
